# Dataframe to find a duplicate in another dataframe and then extract a value from another column in that row

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am new to dataframes and pandas and just need insight on how this might work.

Compare Name Column in Import_tab sheet to Name Column in Name sheet and if there is a match retrieve data from Email Column in Name Sheet and then replace the value in the Email Column in Import_Tab sheet.

I have stored the different sheets into different dataframes

```
Import_tab = pd.read_excel(dump_file, sheet_name='Import')
Name = pd.read_excel(dump_file,sheet_name='Name')
```

Import_tab dataframe:

[image]

Name dataframe:

[image]

The end result in the Import_tab dataframe should be:

[image]

Comment: `Import_tab[['Name']].merge(Name[['Name','email']], how='left', on='Name')`

Comment: Please also see: [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)